# similar tasks on different eloquent events in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run a similar task on some different eloquent events in laravel.

For example Suppose I have a `Question` model. For my purpose, I used `boot()` function on the model like this :

```
class Question extends Model
    public static function boot ()
        {
            parent::boot();
            static::updated(function ($Question) {
                //some Tasks on $Question
            });

            static::updating(function ($Question) {
                //some Tasks on $Question
            });

            static::created(function ($Question) {
                //some Tasks on $Question
            });

            static::creating(function ($Question) {
                //some Tasks on $Question
            });
        }
 }
```

As you see in all events , similar Tasks run and may have large code.
what is best and short approach to do that?

Comment: Fire the same job within all of them, if you'd like.

Comment: Is not there any shortand solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to refactor this code:

1. Run `saved()` and `saving()` instead of the whole four events. `saved()` will substitute both `created()` and `updated()`, while `saving()` will substitute both `creating()` and `updating()`.
2. Fire a the same job inside all of them:

   ```
   public static function boot ()
   {
         Question::saved(function ($question) {
            dispatch(new \App\Jobs\job($question));
         });
   }
   ```
3. Add the code to protected function inside the class (this is the least recommended)

By the way, Model events should be placed in the boot method of a Service Provider, not the Model. Model has no boot method.